# Thomas Hardy's Tess (use of the word 'recommend')

Tags: word-usage

In Thomas Hardy's Tess of the d'Urbervilles (chapter 16, 5th paragraph):

> Tess did not stop at Weatherbury, after this long drive, further than to make a slight nondescript meal at noon **at a cottage to which the farmer recommended her**.

The phrase '*at a cottage to which the farmer recommended her*' seems a bit strange. Does it pass for standard English? Shouldn't it be rewritten as 'at a cottage that the farmer recommended to her'?

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a book from 1891. Patterns of English usage have changed. ***Recommend*** now consistently is used in this sort of pattern:

> A **recommended** B to C.

The word order can change, for instance to make it passive:

> B was **recommended** to C by A.

or:

> C had B **recommended** to them by A.

In all cases, modern usage has it that A is telling C that B is good, or appropriate, or whatever.

However, there are older usages. It can mean committing or guiding someone, as in "commending someone to the monastery".

I wouldn't want to commit to exactly what Hardy meant by this, but the general gist is clear, and almost certainly consistent with reasonably contemporary usage - the farmer caused her to go to the cottage by some means.

Comment: Seems like completely standard English to me, albeit very formal in a modern context. It reads like a classic case of avoiding a sentence with a preposition, although I'll give Hardy a pass on being a pedant: "at a cottage a farmer recommended her to". I still feel the farmer is recommending in the modern sense, and you can recommend a person to a thing, or recommend a thing to a person, and it means the same thing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Re *wouldn't want to commit to exactly what Hardy meant*, I think we can be quite certain Hardy ***didn't*** mean that the farmer had previously contacted the people at the college to tell them they should be welcoming to Tess, which would be our default reading of the syntax today. The usage here is effectively "outdated", but I think there's no doubt it means what we'd phrase today by reversing the direct and indirect objects - *the farmer recommended **the cottage to Tess**,* not ***...Tess to the cottage***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's my personal feeling, but I recognise from the archaic usages of it that I've found described that it could mean the farmer brought her into the cottage (with a possible implication of shutting the door behind her, compelling her to stay or breach good manners). It just being an inversion of direct and indirect object seems more likely, by far.